# Why is my graphical desktop running on TTY1

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, graphics, gnome-shell

I recently installed gnome-shell on my new Archlinux and X is running on TTY1. Is this is a normal behaviour?

`````
screenfetch

                       -`
                      .o+`                 rkmax@satellite
                     `ooo/                 OS: Arch Linux 
                    `+oooo:                Kernel: x86_64 Linux 3.9.9-1-ARCH
                   `+oooooo:               Uptime: 13m
                   -+oooooo+:              Packages: 785
                 `/:-:++oooo+:             Shell: bash
                `/++++/+++++++:            Resolution: 2726x768
               `/++++++++++++++:           DE: Gnome 3.8.2
              `/+++ooooooooooooo/`         WM: Not Found
             ./ooosssso++osssssso+`        WM Theme: Not Found
            .oossssso-````/ossssss+`       GTK2 Theme: Adwaita
           -osssssso.      :ssssssso.      GTK3 Theme: Adwaita
          :osssssss/        osssso+++.     Icon Theme: gnome
         /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-     Font: Ubuntu 11
       `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-   CPU: Intel Core i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.533GHz
      `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:  RAM: 1312MB / 2808MB
     `++:.                           `-/+/  
     .`                                 `/
`````

Comment: Don't know about Arch but this is the default on Fedora 16.

Comment: Yeah I think this is a newer thing, but perhaps also something to do with how X is built or configured, since I notice ubuntu still punts GUI's onto a higher VT.

Comment: @goldilocks Do you mean the `tty` for a graphical session is configured into X at compile time? This seems a bit inflexible...

Comment: @goldilocks i have other question why `WM: Not found` is show if i have installed gnome-shell?

Comment: How do you start Gnome: with GDM or `xinitrc`?

Comment: @jasonwryan i dont have a `.xinitrc` file

Comment: @terdon that line should not be `WM: gnome-shell`